# Phosphorylation alters structure: Specific Example?

Tags: phosphorylation

Why does phosphorylation activate an enzyme?

A common answer to this question is that the introduced phosphate group "alters the structure" of the enzyme.

Can somebody point out a **specific example** of such an alteration? I.e. like a "before/after" illustration?

Or is the whole mechanism of activation still largely uncharacterized?

Comment: check the conformational change in $G \alpha$ subunit of GPCR

Comment: @WYSIWYG has answered the question neatly. Many mechanisms of activation are mostly uncharacterized. It's easy to see why: You need to do X-ray crystallography or extremely clever FRET experiments to see exactly how the structure changes shape. X-ray crystallography is really hard for proteins, especially big, asymmetric enzymes that bind things and don't like to form crystals. So that's why we don't have data on lots more enzymes.

Comment: I have no problem believing that's it's challenging to get the structures. But I am surprised that there is only so little data- many times I find the statement that xyz-pathway is among the most thoroughly characterized cell biology aspects. So I would have thought getting detailed mechanistic insight would have been among the highest priorities.